# Generating new files from a template by finding and replacing, with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a template **LaTeX** file containing a counter **(called "Contador")** inside the text, in a line such as

```
\addplot[] table[]{figure-contador.csv}
```

That counter allows me to include the data from a lot of figures coded in CSV files. The file is named **`test.tex`**.
I want to generate 100 new files from the template say ***test0.tex, test1.tex, test2.tex,*** etc. I thought I could do that easily with sed, and I tried the script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..99} do 
    sed 's/contador/$i/g' test.tex > test$i.tex 
done
```

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `sed "s/contador/$i/g" test.tex > test$i.tex`

Comment: @John1024I: tried it. No luck:  
`generator.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `sed'`
 
`generator.sh: line 3: `sed "s/contador/$i/g" kktest.tex > kktest$i.tex '`

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find how to format the code above in two lines...

Comment: OK.  I see.  There was also a semicolon missing.  I just posted an answer with both problems fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..99}; do
    sed "s/contador/$i/g" test.tex > "test$i.tex"
done
```

There were two issues:

1. `for i in {0..99}` and `do` need to be separated by either a newline or a semicolon.
2. Within single-quotes, shell variables like `$i` are not expanded.  To allow them to be expanded, use double-quotes.

#### Alternative using awk

```
for i in {0..99}; do
    awk -v i="$i" '{gsub(/contador/, i)} 1' test.tex >"test$i.tex"
done
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much, both for the solution and the detailed explanation!